# How can I calculate the $D$ field when all the free charge is on a conductor embedded in a dielectric?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, dielectric

Let $K$ be a bounded piece of conductor, embedded in an isotropic, homogeneous, uniform dielectric of permittivity $\epsilon$.

Let $ \vec r$ be a point in the exterior of the conductor. Let $\rho_f$ be the free charge density, where all the free charge is on $K$.

Can I say that $$
\vec D(r) = \frac{1} {4 \pi \epsilon }\int _{\mathbb{R}^3 }   \frac {\rho_{f}\left(\vec{r}\,’\right)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}\,’|^2}\, d^{3}r' $$ in this case?

(I think this is true when the curl of $\vec P$ vanishes, but I am not sure if this holds in this case since $\vec P$ may be discontinuous on the boundary of $K$.)